# If $m,n \in \mathbb N$ and $c>1$, then $c^m>c^n$ if and only if $m>n$.

Tags: real-analysis

I read a very nice math book and there is one exercise in this book. I have to prove that

> If $m,n \in \mathbb N$ and $c>1$, then $c^m>c^n$ if and only if $m>n$.

The proof is:

> If $m>n$ then $k:=m-n \in \mathbb N$. But $c^k>c>1$ (we can use this fast). Since $c^k=c^{m-n}$ this implies that $c^m>c^n$.

My question is WHY? Why does $c^k=c^{m-n}$ imply that $c^m>c^n$?

Thank you for help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$c^k > 1 \implies c^{m-n} > 1 \implies c^{m-n} \cdot c^n > c^n \implies c^m \cdot c^{-n + n} > c^n \implies \boxed{c^m > c^n}$$

Comment: Thank u! Super!